# nginx frontend forward HTTPS to HTTP with no valid certificate

Tags: nginx

After a little research i suspect the answer might no, nevertheless i will ask anyway.
The situation is there is the NGINX frontend which acts as a reverse proxy for the apache backend. My questions is; is it possible to forward/redirect/... a request to a HTTPS url to a normal HTTP one?

E.G:
 A request comes to the frontend for https://foobar.com is it possible to forward/redirect/.. the request to http://foobar.com without the browser complaining, the need for a certificate or the SSL process to complete before hand?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? And no, it won't work for obvious reasons, namely that a certificate is required to establish the connection and TLS tunnel in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I should hope not!  The whole point of SSL as used by browsers in this scenario is to authenticate the page they are loading.  So, before they deal with any of the content at your page (including redirects of any kind), they will negotiate an SSL connection and check your certificate.

There is absolutely no reason to do what you are trying to do, and besides, it is impossible.  Either get a certificate (at which point, you might as well continue using HTTPS for the connection), or don't give out the https:// URL.

Answer (score -1):

So you want a redirect from port 443 to port 80. One would do that either by using iptables or by creating a non-SSL server on port 443 with a redirect. But I am not sure how various browser would react to that...
Personnaly I would simply not run a server on port 443. Only listen to port 80. It does not break the "SSL" trust.

With **iptables**:
It is assumed that you have incoming connection on ports 80 and 443 allowed. So you would need to do:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <net_if> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
```

Replace `<net_if>` by your network interface name (e.g. eth0)

With NGINX running a "HTTP" server on port 443:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server name foobar.com;

  return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server name foobar.com;

  location / {
    ...
  }
}
```

That should create to HTTP (non https) server on port 80 and 443. Connection on 443 are redirected on port 80. Maybe add `ssl off;` on the server 443 block if the above does not work.

Comment: I think you  misunderstood be, perhaps i should of been more clearer. I want the frontend server (whether through way of ngninx or not) to strip away the HTTPS and make the connection into HTTP. But i want to be able to do that without having a valid SSL cert of the domain that is being requested. So someone comes to https://foobar.com then they get taken to http://foobar.com without having to accept a cert or getting some warnings.

Comment: Sorry, your message is still not 100% clear. But if your goal is to have a "HTTP permanent redirect" on incoming connection on port 443 to port 80, then this is not that easy... I guess you would have to create a non ssl server on port 443, and do the redirection. I am not sure how the browser would react to that... I will modify my answer.